# Random numbers and letters displayed on Android smartphone?

Tags: php, mysql

All my webpages display fine in all browsers that I can see, but I just noticed something weird on mobile devices (HTC One) running the Android operating system (and some iPhones, but not all). The Android browser displays random numbers and letters throughout the page wherever PHP code is present in the file (and not just areas where I'm echoing data). They’re not special characters, which makes me think that this is not a character encoding issue, but rather they look like they could be hex characters – like “c14”, “9e”, “22a”, “92d”, “fe3b”, “3471” (just a few examples) – and they change or come and go each time I refresh the browser. If I keep refreshing, some character patterns will appear again as if it is cycling through something, but I haven't been able to pin-point a pattern. The big issue is that sometimes these things will land in the value of an HTML form’s input tag and mess up the data that is submitted.

I originally thought this could be a character encoding issue, so I double checked that my PHP files are encoded as UTF-8, but that didn't change anything.

Below is a small block of simple code that I've been tinkering with to try and isolate the problem:

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');

if(isset($_GET['seid']) && is_numeric($_GET['seid']) && $_GET['seid'] > 0){
  $sub_event_id = $_GET['seid'];
  $sub_event_id = mysql_real_escape_string($sub_event_id);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT sub_event_id, event_name
                         FROM event_details
                         WHERE sub_event_id=$sub_event_id") or die(mysql_error());

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title><?php echo $row['event_name']; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php echo $row['sub_event_id']; ?>
  </body>
  </html>
<?php } ?>
```

Below is an example of what displays in the browser.

If
$row['event_name'] is, let's say "Party at Joe's"
and
$row['sub_event_id'] is, let's say "1"

This is one of the random examples you see in the browser's "view source":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>22
Party at Joe's
18</title>
</head>
<body>
5
1
11
</body>
</html>
0
```

If I refresh the browser, the random numbers might go away then come back, but the "0" at the bottom is usually there most of the time. Files with more code tend to have random letters included as well. And again, these seem to appear wherever PHP code is present in the file. Sometimes at the very top of the page as well.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is blatantly impossible. Even if you could get PHP to output this from that example code, it would show up in all browsers, not just 'some iPhones and Androids'. The only scenario I can think of would be a bad proxy (and by god, mobile providers have a lot of them). Does a 3G/4G connection happen to be the unifying factor between the 'struck' devices? Still, even that would not explain why it seems to be combined with the PHP tags.

Comment: Did you try to move a html part outside of php if () {...} block and assign results to the variables then use those ones in <title>/<body> tags?

Comment: Niels, 3G/4G doesn't seem to be the unifying factor.  I'm looking on both an iPhone and Android using 4G right now. The Android is displaying the extra characters. The iPhone is not. user3806621, I just tried moving the html out of the php block and assigned the results to variables. The characters are still appearing.  Crazy, I know!

Answer (score 0):

**Fistly** try also adding the older UTF-8 meta setting just incase the browser on that particular device does not look for the new meta attribute:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**Secondly** (this happened to me recently) try retyping the code out manually in a new file, If you have copied code from another source, that source may have been written in an IDE with bad encoding settings in the first place, you may have copied invisible characters from example code into your new script...

**Finally** ensure that the tool you are using to write your script is properly configured for UFT-8 to ensure you are typing out code in the correct encoding.
Even pasting badly encoded code into an IDE with proper encoding settings will **not fix all** character encoding issues.

You may be able to identify if your script contains invisible characters by opening your script with a HEX Editor and looking at the binary, there may be addition bytes that highlight nothing. Sometimes the invisible characters can become visible in a HEX Editor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

- OR -

Notepad++ using Hex Editor Plugin:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/